# Duplicate Key in ini FILE VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, ini

i'm trying to have duplicate keys in ini file like this:

```
[section]
key1 = "value1"
key2 = "value2"
key1 = "value....."

Private Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
  Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
  (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
  ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
  ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
```

Comment: Can you explain the actual question a bit better? What issues are you coming across?

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a section of an INI file. When you request to read "key1" how would you tell the API *which* key you wanted?

Comment: i know that i cannot have duplicate keys in a section of an INI file but i have a configuration file that looks like an ini file. to read all keys, i use a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read your ini file *duplicate keys* into [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) instance.

Something like below might help:

```
System.IO.StreamReader YourIniFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("yourIniFilePath");
string fileText = YourIniFile.ReadToEnd();  
string[] splitText = fileText.Split(new string[] {"\n", "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
ILookup<string, string> ini = splitText.ToLookup(key=> key.Substring(0, key.IndexOf("=")),
                               value => value.Substring(value.IndexOf("=")));
```